# c++ STL vector is not acccepting the copy constructor

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

I wrote a code ( c++,visual studio 2010) which is having a vector, even I though copy const is declared, but is still showing that copy const is not declared

Here the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "Default A is acting" << endl ; }
    A(A &a) { cout << "Copy Constructor of A is acting" << endl ; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b=a;
    vector<A> nothing;
    nothing.push_back(a);

    int n;
    cin >> n;
}
```

The error I got is

> Error 1 error C2558: class 'A' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory 48 1 delete

Anybody please help me

Comment: Please go back and accept answers to some of your previous questions, or people may be unwilling to answer this one.

Comment: how to do that, actually  I don't know I am new to SO

Comment: Go back to questions you've asked, and click the checkmark ✔ next to the best answer.

Comment: Note that like Neil Butterworth said, copy constructors *can* be written to take non-const references. But for standard containers, your copy constructor should use a const reference as parameter type

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Copy constructor should take the object as a const reference, so it should be:

```
A(const A &a){ cout << "Copy Constructor of A is acting" << endl; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Think copy constructors take **const** ref's

try

```
A(const A &a) { cout << "Copy Constructor of A is acting" << endl ; }
```

Hope that helps